# Regex reemplazar devolviendo parte del mismo elemento

Tags: regex

Estoy intentando crear un patrón regular y no sé bien como hacerlo. Necesito un patrón regex para reemplazar cualquier letra mayúsculas seguida por un barra baja en la letra, es decir, reemplazar por ejemplo:

```
A_
```

y obtener simplemente la letra que ya había, en este caso sería obtener:

```
A
```

Mi problema es que no se bien como devolver el mismo elemento. El patrón inicial sería `[A-Z]_` y con eso obtengo el resalten en los elementos que quiero, pero ahora necesito que me devuelva la letra que ya había (sin el barra baja final).

Por si sirve de ayuda para la respuesta: En los textos que tengo que reemplazar hay más barra bajas, así que no puedo simplemente eliminarlas todas. Lo que realmente tengo que reemplazar es A_1, A_2, B_1, etc. y tengo que dejarlo en A1 A2 B1 etc. (combinaciones de todas las letrás y números). La posición de por ejemplo A_1 es por en medio de un texto de mayor longitud, pero en todo el texto solo hay un texto coincidente con A_ o con A_1 (la letra o el número que sea según cada caso).

¿Alguna idea sobre como conseguirlo?

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las partes que quieras guardar, las pones entre paréntesis, y luego las recuperas usando $n siendo n el numero de paréntesis ($1, $2...)
Por ejemplo ([A-Z])_ lo reemplazas por $1
Código en JavaScript:

```js
const reg = /([A-Z])_/g
const str = "A_1 B_2 C_3"
const newStr = str.replace(reg, "$1");
console.log(newStr);
```