# RegEx: Reemplazar texto con RegEx, utilizando la ocurrencia como parte del texto reemplazado

Tags: javascript, regex

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es una función que le dé formato a una fórmula matemática simple.

Si el usuario introduce `((2* 3) +2 /3)9`, devolverá `((2*3)+2/3)*9` (quitando espacios, y añadiendo `*` entre `)9`, y alguna cosa más). He conseguido todo menos la última parte de  añadir el `*`.

¿Cómo podría buscar `)[0-9]` para luego utilizar lo que devuelva el bloque `[0-9]` para cambiarlo a `)\*[0-9]`?

Con esto he conseguido encontrar las ocurrencias, me falta reemplazarlas:
`formula.replace(/)[0-9]/g, '')`

Aclaraciones:

- No tine porqué ser con RegEx. Simplemente he pensado que sería más rápido y elegante que hacer 10 `if`s
- Puede haber más de 1 ocurrencia, en cuyo caso quiero reemplazar todas
- El `String` inicial no será siempre el mismo (como en [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/599193/regex-reemplazar-devolviendo-parte-del-mismo-elemento) pregunta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes utilizar esta RegEx:

```
(.*\))(\d+)
```

Que se traduce a:

```
(          // abrimos grupo #1
 .*        // cualquier caracter, cero o mas veces
 \)        // el caracter ")"
)          // cerramos grupo #1
(          // abrimos grupo #2
  \d+      // digito, una o mas veces
)          // cerramos grupo #2
```

#### Demo:

```js
let formula = '((2* 3) +2 /3)9';

// Limpiar espacios
formula = formula.replace(/\s+/g, '');
// Agregar *
formula = formula.replace(/(.*\))(\d+)/g, '$1*$2');
//
console.log(formula);
```